# Search for Word in headers and set column to be used for calculations in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to carry out calculations on columns in an Excel spreadsheet.  The column names are: LowLimit,  HighLimit and   MeasValue
"I am only able to right now 'hard code' the column numbers to carry out the calculations (as shown in the code below).  The code works great if the column positions remain the same.  However, the position of the columns changes throughout the workbook but they are always in the same order.  For example, on sheet one, the headers LowLimit, HighLimit and MeasValue will be in positions J, K, L respectively.  On sheet 25, they will change positions to   G, H, I respectively.

How to search for the header positions and then use that in the calculations compared to having them hard coded as I have done below?

Here is what I have so far (code superbly edited by [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams)):

```
Sub SearchFolders()
'UpdatebySUPERtoolsforExcel2016
    Dim xOut As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xWks As Worksheet
    Dim InterSectRange As Range
    Dim lowLimCol As Integer
    Dim hiLimCol As Integer
    Dim measCol As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xWb = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each xWks In xWb.Sheets
    xRow = 1
    With xWks
        .Cells(xRow, 16) = "Meas-LO"
        .Cells(xRow, 17) = "Meas-Hi"
        .Cells(xRow, 18) = "Min Value"
        .Cells(xRow, 19) = "Marginal"
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        lowLimCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("LowLimit", xWks.Range("1:1"), 0)
        hiLimCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("HighLimit", xWks.Range("1:1"), 0)
        measLimCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("MeasValue", xWks.Range("1:1"), 0)
        .Range("P2").Formula = "=L2-J2"
        .Range("P2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("P2:P" & LastRow)
        .Range("Q2").Formula = "=K2-L2"
        .Range("Q2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow)
        .Range("R2").Formula = "=min(P2,Q2)"
        .Range("R2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("R2:R" & LastRow)

        .Range("S2").Formula = "=IF(AND(R2>=-3, R2<=3), ""Marginal"", R2)"
        .Range("S2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("S2:S" & LastRow)

     End With
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turn it back on

 Next xWks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set integer variables for the three column headers (e.g. LowLimCol)

Find these with:

`lowLimCol = Application.Worksheetfunction.Match("LowLimit", ws.Range("1:1"), 0)`

You can then use these variables by defining ranges using `cells` e.g.

`range("A1:A5")`

can be rewritten as

`range(cells(1, LowLimCol).address, cells(5, LowLimCol).address)`

**EDIT: 2nd part after comment -**

If you didn't need to floodfill the formula you could have just put the actual value of the sum in the cell:

```
.Range("P2").Value = .Cells(2, measLimCol).Value - .Cells(2, lowLimCol).Value
```

However, since you're flooding that formula down to the last row, you can use concatenation to swap between the formula strings "=" and "-" and the VBA coded cell addresses, for example:

```
.Range("P2").Formula = "=" & Cells(2, measLimCol).Address & "-" & Cells(2, lowLimCol).Address
```

This will come out with absolute references in cell "P2" as "=$L$2-$J$2" so in order to be able to flood fill this you need to get rid of the $$$ by specifying `FALSE` after the `cells(x,y).address` parts e.g. `cells(x,y).address(false,false)`

This means the line would be:

```
.Range("P2").Formula = "=" & Cells(2, measLimCol).Address(false, false) & "-" & Cells(2, lowLimCol).Address (false, false)
```

Hope that helps! You could also fill the entire range in one go so the TWO lines

```
.Range("P2").Formula = "=L2-J2"
.Range("P2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("P2:P" & LastRow)
```

Could become:

```
.Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Formula = "=" & Cells(2, measLimCol).Address (False, False) & "-" & Cells(2, lowLimCol).Address (False, False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  I have updated the code partially as per your suggestion.  How do I put the found cell number into the equations?  Please see updated code.  For example, how to replace `.Range("P2").Formula = "=L2-J2"` with `.Range("P2").Formula = "=measLimCol-lowLimCol"`?Thanks!

Comment: Well it can get a bit clunky and to make it a bit easier to see I'll just edit my answer instead of commenting here...